# Setting home computer as www web server

Tags: webserver, firewall, fedora, lamp

I know I'm seriously missing some steps.

I need to set my home Fedora 19 running computer as a web server and available it to internet.
Its behind a normal home broadband modem connection. my ip shows as 10x.24x.5x.xx (masked for security reasons)

1. I've install LAMP bundle. And `httpd` running and tested with `wget http://localhost`
2. Configured the `system-config-firewall` to open http, ftp ports

However when I'm `wget http://10x.24x.5x.xx` (my own IP via another computer) I'm getting a connection timeout error.

Could anyone specify the missing steps?

Comment: Is your modem doing a NAT or do you have the IP 10x.24x.5x.xx directly assigned to one of the interfaces on your PC?

Comment: Have you port forwarded port 80 to the computer?

Comment: It is depend on model of your broadband modem. In some bad cases there is no ways to do what you need.

Comment: Yep, we need the answer to  mauro.stettler's question (+1) and your modem model also.

Comment: @mauro.stettler I'm not sure how to check it. This is a normal 3G broadband modem with a dynamic IP from ISP.
Newest find is when I search for my IP on google or somewehere I/m getting 10x.24x.5x.xx
However when viewing the network connection information it shows an different IP address. And this IP works when request with http. How'd that happened?

Comment: @chipperyman573 My computer is the only device which connected to the modem. Also this is not a router.

Comment: Look up how to configure your modem's router feature.  Set your PC to be in the DMZ if it has that option, as this will simply redirect all unrecognized packets directly to your PC.